# Display loading gif before any .js is loaded

Tags: javascript, loading, gif

I have a gif that is on the screen saying loading, and once the page is loaded this image fads out and my animations etc begin.

What i want to achieve is to have my loading.gif visible before any of my javascript is loaded.

Unfortunatly i am picking up someone elses code and it is fairly complex so i can't simply move my .js calls to the bottom of my html or wrap everything in a window.load. I was just wondering if there is anyway with js. or otherwise that i can force my gif to display before anything else is done.

I appologise for this being quite a vague question.

Comment: Can you modify the HTML?

Comment: You can load your gif in the `<head>` section of the HTML before any of the JS files are loaded.

Comment: The only sure-fire thing you can do is to run the JavaScript in a "load" handler (either for the window or the image itself).

Comment: Ok, well everything that can be handed in an on.load is.
The loading gif is the first item in the HTML.

How can i load the image in the <head> ?

Comment: @user1498426 by putting it in the <head> tags